# NO ME CARGA LA PAGINA WEB AL COMPILAR EL PROYECTO mvc DE ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ayer cree desde 0 un proyecto mvc, quise compilar para asegurarme de que todo funciona de manera correcta y me arroja el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-estoy utilizando visual estudio code, en el debugger utilizo la opción ".NET (web)" compilo y me arroja el error.

**necesito ayuda porfa y gracias muy agradecido**

Comment: que version de .net usas?

Comment: la ultima que esta en linea .Netcore 3.1

Comment: Prueba a ir al IIS, al examen de Directorios de tu sitio y dale a 'Habilitar' en la parte derecha.
Reinicia servicios. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHAtg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHAtg.png)